# Dynamically created button click event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to create a "vote" button for each row of a query. Therefore I have to do it dynamically. However, for some reason when I am adding a button dynamically and creating it's event handler within the `page_init()` method- the button is created but the event is not firing when clicked.

This is the code I am using. I have also tried to use `page_load()` instead of `page_init()` but the result is the same.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["user"] == null) Response.Redirect("../login/Login.aspx", true);

    string id = Request.QueryString["iss"];
    if (id == null || id == "") Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx");

    SqlRow issue = Database.Query("SELECT * FROM issues WHERE id=?", id)[0];
    SqlRes options = Database.Query("SELECT * FROM options WHERE issue=?", id);
    issueTitle.Title = issue["title"].ToString();
    issueText.InnerText = issue["issue"].ToString();

    if (options.Count == 0) return;
    int w = 90 / options.Count;
    foreach(SqlRow option in options)
    {
        bool voted = Database.Query("SELECT * FROM options_votes WHERE opt=? AND userid=?", option["Id"], Session["user"]).Count>0;

        Part p = new Part
        {
            W = w,
        };
        var title = new HtmlGenericControl("h2");
        title.Attributes["class"] = "dark";
        title.InnerText = option["title"].ToString();
        p.Controls.Add(title);
        Button vote = new Button
        {
            Text = "VOTE",

        };
        vote.Click += (se, ev) =>
        {
            bool nvoted = Database.Query("SELECT * FROM options_votes WHERE opt=? AND userid=?", option["Id"], Session["user"]).Count > 0;
            if (nvoted)
            {
                Database.Query("DELETE FROM options_votes WHERE opt=? AND userid=?", option["Id"], Session["user"]);
                vote.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0x17, 0x25, 0x2a);
            }
            else
            {
                Database.Query("INSERT INTO options_votes (opt, userid) VALUES (?, ?)", option["Id"], Session["user"]);
                vote.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        };
        if (voted) vote.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        vote.Attributes["class"] = "vote";
        p.Controls.Add(vote);

        issueTitle.Controls.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Other answers for similar questions say to add the button with `visible=false`, but in my case I cannot add the button in the .aspx page, it has to be in the code-behind.

Comment: you could bind the result of the query to a Repeater instead, and avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
By adding `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` to the button, I have managed to get the click event working.